# Why do you need "require 'bundler/setup'"?

Tags: ruby, bundler

In almost every Sinatra example I've seen, despite what it does, it always has the following two lines:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
```

In most examples, removing the 'bundler/setup' require seems to have no breaking effect, so I'm confused about when/where I need to include this.

I hate using things without knowing exactly the reason for it being there, so I was hoping someone could explain why I need both lines and what they do?

Comment: See http://bundler.io/v1.10/git.html for better examples of usage, All your answers are telling you why. But do you know where your gems are being installed when you use urls other than 'https://rubygems.org'? Look in your gems/version/ directory for bundler folder not the gem itself. It will have a folder that says gems and that's where they wind up being when bundler installs them other than rubygems source.

Comment: You can even tell bundler where to install them like a vendor folder with your app and then load them from there also. See http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_install.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It ensures you're loading Gemfile defined gems. Please have a look at the documentation here https://bundler.io/v1.12/bundler_setup.html

Comment: apparently it does not obey the GEM_HOME or GEM_PATH environment variables.. ?

Comment: So if you include `require "bundler/setup"`, do you not have to use `bundle exec` when starting the script?

Comment: Yes, that's right. By including `require "bundler/setup"` you don't need to use `bundle exec` when starting your script.

Comment: but what is the difference between require 'bundler' and require 'bundler/setup'?

Answer (score 10):

There is a practical explanation:

Let's say we want to use a gem called pristine_text from the github master branch

Gemfile:

```
gem "pristine_text", github: "nurettin/pristine_text"
```

main.rb: (wrong)

```
require "pristine_text"
# error, can't find pristine_text
```

require can't find it, because the gem is not in a path ruby can see. If you look at the actual path of the gem, you will see that it is under

`/pristine-text-some_commit_id`

main.rb: (right)

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "pristine_text"
# no error
```

The error is gone, because now you load bundler with your dependencies' load paths.

Answer (score 9):

#### [Understanding Bundler's setup process](http://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-bundler-setup-process/)

[Brian Storti wrote the best article I can find on Bundler setup - from which the quote is taken](http://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-bundler-setup-process/).

> #### Understanding what is happening
>
> To put it shortly, what Bundler is doing is removing from the $LOAD_PATH everything that is not defined in the Gemfile. The $LOAD_PATH (or just $:) is the global variable that tells Ruby where it should look for things that are required, so if a dependency is not in the Gemfile, it’s not going to be in the $LOAD_PATH, and then Ruby has no way to find it.
>
> #### Show me the code
>
> [This](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/d3922e972570f6bd1144dfeade35d81b5830ac6e/lib/bundler/setup.rb) is the file that is loaded when we require 'bundler/setup', and the important thing here is the [Bundler.setup](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/d3922e972570f6bd1144dfeade35d81b5830ac6e/lib/bundler/setup.rb#L8) call. This setup first [cleans the load path](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/3c6c010da1f4d34d9bff7ddb374e0ef6a11de5c3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L11), and then [activates](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/3c6c010da1f4d34d9bff7ddb374e0ef6a11de5c3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L18) just the gems that are defined in the Gemfile, which basically means [adding them to the $LOAD_PATH variable](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/3c6c010da1f4d34d9bff7ddb374e0ef6a11de5c3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb#L39).

Note: I've updated the "show me the code" links as they went to master branch which has changed.

Answer (score 5):

The Bundle setup "clears" the load path, so the subsequent attempt to require something that is not in Gemfile will result of the load error.