# explanation of application.rb file in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of how a rails app initializes. I'm looking over the **config/application.rb** file and I'm confused by these three lines:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

From what I can tell all three of these lines are loading the gems used by the Rails Application. **boot.rb** appears to load all the gems as does **Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)**. Why is it necessary to have all three lines of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly correct, and you can verify what is "needed" by disabling one line at a time in a working Rails app.

- `require_relative 'boot'`: Application still runs.
- `require 'rails/all'`: Method not found error for a gem not listed in my Gemfile (one of [Rails' built-ins](https://github.com/rails/rails) (require 'rails/all')
- `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`: Method not found for gem from Gemfile.

So, the second and third are independent and essential. boot.rb's call to **bundler/setup** cannot stand in for either of the other two, because its function is actually to [clean the load path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295091/3960558) by making sure that only Gemfile gems are included, and everything else is removed. See the last line of the [Bundler setup source](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/d3922e972570f6bd1144dfeade35d81b5830ac6e/lib/bundler/setup.rb). So, while the app runs, it could be running with access to other gems that you did not intend to include, and give you a false sense that the app is working when *it could fail for another user who only installed the Gemfile dependencies*.

So you may get away with only the second and third in the short term, but would definitely want all three on anything that someone else may someday have to execute. The overhead is minimal so I would not remove any of these.

Comment: Thank you MBerka. The part I'm still not understanding is why the second line is needed. Doesn't the third line include all of our gems?

Comment: @nflauria No, it only includes the gems from the Gemfile. I have edited my response to fix a missing link to the Rails source in the second item, which shows the gems that are built into Rails. The likes of ActiveRecord, ActiveStorage and ActionMailer are widely used, and often omitted the Gemfile, because of that line.

Answer (score 2):

```
require_relative 'boot'
```

Sets up Bundler and load paths for gems

```
require 'rails/all'
```

This loads the rails gems. It can be replaced in order to explicitly require only the rails gems that you need (i.e. `require "action_mailer/railtie`"

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

This requires gems listed in your Gemfile by default. If you remove this line, you would have to require each gem by hand.